# TFS 2010 Backup Plan Fails with Error About AdminPTHelper.exe

Tags: backup, sharepoint, team-foundation-server

My company has a TFS 2010 Server running SharePoint 2010 locally.  Originally we were just doing a database backup of all the TFS databases (MSSQL 2008 also run locally) but I came across some Microsoft literature which specified that you should use the Power Tools Backup Plan to ensure each database you backup is in the same transaction state when you do a restore.

So I installed the August 2011 TFS Server Power Tools pack and open up the Team Foundation Server Administration Console.  I click on the Team Foundation Backups item on the right, and click the "Create Backup Plan."

After waiting a few minutes I get an error stating that AdminPTHelper.exe has stopped working.

I did some research and it looks like this guy was having the same problem: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/view/Discussions/5#2376

From what I can tell the hostnames match between the Team Foundation Server Administration Console and the SharePoint Alternate Access Mapping.

Any other thing this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error ended up being that I didn't have access to the SharePoint_Config database on the same system.  It's odd this would cause an error as Microsoft recommends NOT backing up that database but apparently it's doing some check on that database when initially starting up the application and if it can't access it, it fails.